# ScalaStyle using grade return an error

Tags: gradle, scalastyle

I'm looking for *scalaStyle* using gradle. Can you explain how to do it?

I've tried [this](https://github.com/ngbinh/gradle-scalastyle-plugin) link, but I get an error:

> Error:(110, 0) Could not find method scalaStyle() for arguments
>   [build_5ig236mubh10t6rxyt8apdkfi$_run_closure4@46b9e954] on root
>   project .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is a sample `build.gradle` that uses `scalaStyle` plugin:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.github.ngbinh.scalastyle:gradle-scalastyle-plugin_2.11:0.9.0' //version 1.0.0 is not published yet.
  }
}

apply plugin: 'scalaStyle'

scalaStyle {
  configLocation = '/path/to/scalaStyle.xml'
  includeTestSourceDirectory = true
  source = 'src/main/scala'
  testSource = 'src/test/scala'
}
```

You need to define `buildscript` block to declare dependencies for the script itself. When it's done a plugin needs to be applied. Finally you can use `scalaStyle` block to configure the plugin's behaviour.

Comment: @kevinjoeiy, no no idea. You need to read the docs or ask another question.